# jquery append and remove that

Tags: jquery

I like to have a h3 title with a little caracter that say "expand me"

it will look like that : category xyz [+]

i like a function in jquery to chage/remove the + to minus when click.. i know how to append text to string but not how to remove it or just a part..

if you have a better approch feel free to tell me.. thanks !

---

note : implement the .remplace function... but dont work as expected
[you can see it here](http://missfrisette.com/index.php) ... the problem i used jquery 1.4 switch to 1.4.3 now it work !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you *must* have the +/- in the same h3 as the rest of the header text, I'd do it with a regex replace. Here's how I'd do it then:

```
$("body").delegate("#header a", "click", function(eventObj) {
    if ($(this).text().match(/\+/)) {
        $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/\+/, "-"));
    } else {
        $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/-/, "+"));
    }
});
```

You can see this working over at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6tMU/).

Comment: NICE! This is exactly what I needed! : )

Comment: This is the answer I will choose because it make me learn something new, but in my site it don't work now... can you point me the problem ?

Comment: @marc-andre menard The problem is that on your site, you have an anchor tag inside that h3. So you need to grab the anchor's text instead of the h3's text. I've updated my answer to reflect this. Please try that.

Comment: sorry .. but still dont work.... i will not touch the code until tomorrow.. and please telle me what i am doing wrong... just a copy/paste! sorry !

Comment: @marc-andre menard I've double-checked my answer and made any clarifications that I could. This works in the linked js fiddle and should work on your site. Try copying it again. I *must* stress that if I were you, I would go with @Damo or @BrunoLM's method, because in reality they are more elegant and they are how I'd do it. My answer is solely if, for some reason, you *must have the entire text inside of one h3 element*.

Comment: the problem... me!, i was using jquery 1.4, switch to 1.4.3, and it work fine !, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Much easier just to toggle the visibility of existing elements.

**HTML**

```
<h3>Category XYZ
   <span id="toggle">
      <a href="#" class="expand" title="expand me">[+]</a>
      <a href="#" class="hide" title="hide me">[-]</a>
   </span>
</h3>
<div id="toggleContent">This is the text of category XYZ</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("span#toggle a").click(function() {
   $("div#toggleContent").toggle();
   $("span#toggle a").toggle();
});
```

**CSS**

```
div#toggleContent { display: none; }
span#toggle a.hide { display: none; }
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/damianharvey/jppRq/)** that you can try this out on.

Answer (score 0):

$("#idOfObject").html("[-]");

don't shoot me if I'm wrong, going by memory :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery html or text functions to accomplish this:

```
$("#your-selector").text("category xyz[-]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the little character in it's very own `<span>`, and give that `<span>` a "class" or "id" value.  Then you can use the class or id from Javascript to find that part of the text specifically and change it. This will have the added advantage of making that little bit of text, so meaningless among the rest of your page content, all smug and haughty in its linguistic intelligibility, well that little character will just be **special**.  Its quality of life will be improved dramatically, and that sort of thing really comes through on a subliminal level to your users.

Comment: what is your method of choice to show the "possibility" to view more by licking on something... show me some example of site you have done

Comment: If the changeable text is in a `<span>` with an "id" then it can be changed very easily. That is completely basic web programming.

Answer (score 0):

put the characters in a spans something like

```
<span class=expandPlus>[+]</span>
```

then you can use something like

```
$("h3").click(function() {
  $(this).children('expandPlus').html('[-]')
  .
  .
  .
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to expand/collapse I suggest you do make a structure similar to this:

**[See this example on jsFiddle.](http://www.jsfiddle.net/TPzMw/)**

Each `a` is related to one `div`. The `href` is the selector for the content div.

```
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li>Category 01 <a href="#cat01">[+]</a></li>
        <li>Category 02 <a href="#cat02">[+]</a></li>
        <li>Category 03 <a href="#cat03">[+]</a></li>
    </ul>
    <br />
    <div id="categories">
        <div id="cat01">content 01</div>
        <div id="cat02">content 02</div>
        <div id="cat03">content 03</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here I'm using [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), each time you click the element the function index increases by 1 until it reach the max, then it go back to 0. So with two functions it will alternate between them in each click. By doing so you can toggle `[-]` and `[+]`. This will only work properly assuming all categories starts with the same state. If they are not necessarily collapsed at first run you will have to modify this function to check the `a` content for `[+]` or `[-]`.

```
$("#container ul > li > a").toggle(function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.text("[-]"); // change the text
    // select content div using href as the selector
    $($this.attr("href")).css("display", "block");
    // prevent any other behavior
    e.preventDefault();
},
function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $(this).text("[+]"); // switch to collapsed view
    $($this.attr("href")).css("display", null);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```